# Proof for showing that the Euclidean algorithm finds $\gcd$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is the below proof enough to show that the Euclidean algorithm computes the $\gcd$ for $a, b, q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ with
$a = bq + r$ then $(a, b)=(b, r)$.

It works by showing that any common divisor of $a,b$ is also a common divisor of $b,r$, and vice-versa. If the set of common divisors of $a,b$ is the same as the set of common divisors of $b,r$, then both must have the same greatest common divisor.

1. Suppose that an integer $n$ divides both $a, b$. 
    Then, $n \mid a, b \implies \exists s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a = ns, b = nt$. 
   Also, can find another linear combination: 
   $r = a − bq = ns − ntq = n(s − tq)$.
   Therefore $n|r$.
2. Suppose that $n \mid b, r$. Then there exist suitable integers, $s, t$ with $b = sn, r = tn$. 
   Substituting $a = bq + r = snq + tn = n(sq + t) \implies n \mid a.$

--
If this proof is okay, then the second issue is : why does this proof  not assume that there is something like $\gcd=n$ as an assumption, so that $n\mid a,b,r$.

Comment: That proof certainly is not enough.  It states if you did the first step of the algorithm  But nothing about how to continue or how to find any of the common divisors.  It merely assumes you know one, $n$ and that you can find a few new items that $n$ divides.

Comment: @fleablood I also felt intuitively, but verbalizing was not possible. Thanks for that. Is it possible to make it complete?

Comment: You are only missing saying that $0\leq r<b$ and therefore passing from $(a,b)$ to $(b,r)$ the minimum of the absolute values of the elements of the pair decreased. Since it can't decrease for ever, eventually it becomes zero and once you get zero $(x,0)=x$.

Comment: @treeleaf Thanks for this crucial insight.

Comment: @treeleaf So, I hope that the proof can be made complete by having in step 1, $n_1$; in the next step taking $n_2$, and so on for all the steps till for the $n$th step, only one non-zero term is left. In the last step, the non-zero value can be taken as : $n_n$. Then, equating all these value of $n$ from the $n$ equalities: $n_1=n_2 =\ldots =n_n= \gcd$.